# Gradle override Idea's run configs

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When using the Idea plugin in Gradle back in the days I was able to override run configurations like this:

```
idea {
  project {
    runConfigurations {
      module = project(':sub-project')
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to be deprecated now and I cannot seem to find a way to do it. Also I don't remember if it applied this setting to all run configurations or just created one new run config...

Is there any way to configure Idea through gradle so that **every run configuration** used the same module for classpath?

I want to use the `root` module to be used instead of the actual `submodule` from which I am running.